# Flutter ListTile collapse issue

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

i was searching how we can put collapse option on List, everything in search result was about `listview`, i want to set collapse option on my `ListTile` list, when user will `tap on title` then `subtitle` will be visible under title.
there was option of using `ExpansionTile()`, but flutter documentations says it's not valid now.

```
child: ListTile(
      title: Text(
        "i am visible title",
      ),
      subtitle: Text("i am hidden data, when you will tap on title i will be visible"),
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using `statefulwidget`, you can hide and display the `subtitle` in `setState()` using  `bool` datatype on `onTap` method call.

If you are not using `statefulwidget`, then you need to update your class first to be `statefulwidget`.

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53675372/how-to-access-listtile-subtitle-programmatically) SO answer for more details.